# Rails 3: Custom Routes Resulting in 'undefined local variable or method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In routes.rb:

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy] do
  collection do
    get :inbox
  end
```

In my controller:

```
def inbox
  <stuff>
end
```

In my view (using haml):

```
=link_to 'Inbox', inbox_conversations, :id => 'load-inbox', :class => 'message-control-highlight', :remote => true
```

I get the following error on page load:

```
undefined local variable or method `inbox_conversations' for #<#<Class:0x3d51470>:0x3d59198>
```

In my view, if I replace inbox_conversations with a "#", I don't get any errors on page load. I've tried appending inbox_conversation with likely classes, such as current_user and current_user.mailbox. I've also tried changing the routing from collection to member--and even taking it out of any collection/member block. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `inbox_conversations_path` or `inbox_conversations_url`

`=link_to 'Inbox', inbox_conversations_path, :id => 'load-inbox', :class => 'message-control-highlight', :remote => true`

Answer (score 1):

You need to append `_path` or `_url` to your routes, e.g.

```
= link_to 'Inbox', inbox_conversations_path
```

See the complete Rails Routing guide for all the details:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thank you both. That was just the answer I needed.